# Remove or change null data of array

Tags: php

I'm trying to plot an array, but if one date is NULL, the value go to 1/1/1970.

I have the code:

```
    $date1 = $row['date_initial'];
    $date2 = $row['date_end'];
    $value = $row['value'];


    $data1 = array(strtotime($date1)*1000,$value);
    $data2 = array(strtotime($date2)*1000,$value);

    $data8[] = array($data1,$data2);

    echo json_encode($data8);
```

I get this array:

**[[[1456531200000,"-12"],[1456704000000,"-12"]],[[1456531200000,"-16"],[0,"-16"]],[[1456617600000,"-13"],[1456790400000,"-13"]],[[1456704000000,"-14"],[0,"-14"]]]**

It would be possible to change the null value date and to put the current date until the date is not empty?
or remove this pair of array?

I proved:

```
    $data8 = array_map('array_filter', $data8);
    $data8 = array_filter($data8);
```

but it doesn't work in this case...

Comment: Unset($array[0]); not sure it works though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test it while init

```
if( ! ($data1 = strtotime($date1))) $data1 = time();
$data1 = array($date1*1000,$value);
```

Comment: I saw it as a comment first, then it got removed and I was a bit surprised as it's a simple and good solution.

Comment: i was mistaken in my comment. The solution require two statements :)

Comment: Either way, it's still a solution worthy of an upvote

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `0` timestamps with today's (mid-night) timestamp as follows:

```
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) * 1000; // convert to milliseconds
foreach($data8 as &$period) {
    if(!$period[0][0]) $period[0][0] = $today;
    if(!$period[1][0]) $period[1][0] = $today;
}
```